# MYSQL Query using SUM

Tags: mysql

How can I make this select the 7500 or greater from the ON_HAND VALUE column?

" List the part number part descrtiption and onhand value for each part whose on hand value is at least $7,500. Assign ON_HAND_VALUES as the computed column."

This is what I have so far, I tried subquerys IN statements but I cant figure it out.

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION, SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE) AS ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM PART
WHERE SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE)'7500'
GROUP BY PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION;
```

Part Table

```
PART_NUM    DESCRIPTION     ON_HAND     CLASS   WAREHOUSE   PRICE

AT94       Iron               50         HW         3       24.95
BV06       Home Gym           45         SG         2       794.95
CD52       Microwave Oven     32        AP          1       165.00
DL71       Cordless Drill     21        HW          3       129.95
DR93       Gas Range           8        AP          2       495.00
DW11       Washer             12        AP          3       399.99
FD21       Stand Mixer        22        HW          3       159.95
KL62       Dryer              12        AP          1       349.95
KT03       Dishwasher          8        AP          3       595.00
KV29       Treadmill           9        SG          2       1390.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use `where`, you have to use `having` with aggregate functions:

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION, SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE) AS ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM PART
GROUP BY PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION;
HAVING SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE)'7500'
```

`where` is evaluated before `group`ing and `sum`ming happens, `having` evaluates on the result set, after records are filtered and grouped

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used.

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION, SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE) AS ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM PART
GROUP BY PART_NUM
HAVING SUM(ON_HAND * PRICE)  > '7500'
ORDER BY PART_NUM;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two people are wrong. I know for a fact this is correct:

```
SELECT PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION, (ON_HAND * PRICE) AS ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM PART
WHERE (ON_HAND * PRICE) >= 7500
```